# What is an assignment matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dirichlet-distribution

I'm trying to implement a topic model using a Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) algorithm. I'm using sentences as my dataset. What is Ck in the given instructions?

The instructions are as follows:
For dataset D:
 Run LDA with k topics on D to produce assignment matrix Ck

Its on page 29 of this pdf
http://sambrody.info/Lectures/Brody_aspect-sentiment_Google.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the matrix that assigns topics to each document. You can use it to look up which documents have a give topic and which topics are found in a given document.